# Copy Images from One Sheet to another in Excel (Images not stored in Cells)

Tags: excel, vba

I got a code to copy Images from a folder to my excel worksheet1, but the code doesn't really store them in the cells (is there someway I could modify the code to store them in the cells). I want the images from worksheet1 to be copied in worksheet2 wherever there is a match (scan1.jpg etc)

Code written to copy Images from a folder based on extension match of the image files.

```
Sub Insert()

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objPic As Picture
    Dim rngCell As Range

    strFolder = "Z:\Images\" 'change the path accordingly
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If

    Set rngCell = Range("C1") 'starting cell

    strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "*.jpg", vbNormal) 'filter for .png files

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
        With objPic
            .Left = rngCell.Left
            .Top = rngCell.Top
            .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

I expect to store images in cells if possible (so that I can simply vlookup/hlookup and match these images in the second worksheet)

This is Code result:
[image: This is Code result]

This is the worksheet I want the images to be inserted in:
[image: This is the worksheet I want the images to be inserted in]

Comment: `objPic.Copy` ?

Comment: Or `Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes(i).Copy`